# Request help in converting mac address format to different format

Tags: java, mac-address

It has been a while since I used java.  I am trying to convert a mac address from 00:00:00:00:00:00 format to 0000.0000.0000 format.  The program is very basic and just asks the user to enter the mac address. It should then convert it and display the converted mac address.  I think I am close but just do not know how to get the format correct.  The output I get now has the . in the right spot but I do not know how to take out the colons.  Any help is appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;

public class macAdd {

public static void main(String[] args)
    {           
    Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String mac;
    System.out.print("Copy and paste the MAC address from system :  ");
    mac = userinput.next();

    char macDivide = '.';
    String newMac = mac.replaceAll("(.{4})", "$1"+macDivide);

    System.out.println("Paste the following result into the system");
    System.out.println(" This is the correct mac " + newMac);              
}
```

Comment: if the `.` are in the right place and everything just call `newMac = newMac.replaceAll(":", "");` that should work

Answer (score 6):

You can use something like this to convert:

```
String mac = "00:00:00:00:00:00";
mac.replaceAll("(\\d{2}):(\\d{2})", "$1$2").replace(':', '.');
```

It works by replacing all of the `00:00` with `0000` (removing the colon). This leaves you with `0000:0000:0000`, then you just replace the colon with a period.

Take it for a spin [on ideone](http://ideone.com/Ycc47z).

Comment: Use `replaceAll` if you want to use regex syntax. In other cases use `replace`. So please change `.replaceAll(":", ".")` to `replace(":",".")` or even better `replace(':','.')` since `replace(char, char)` doesn't even internally use regex engine (it is simple loop which iterates over array which replaces our characters).

Comment: **Beware** that the digits in MAC addresses are hexadecimal digits. So instead of "\\d", use the classes "\\p{XDigit}" or "[0-9a-fA-F]" in your pattern.